# RSA encryption in C#: What part defines the public key?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've generated a new public/private key pair and exported it as an XML string:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);  
string publicPrivateKey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);
```

The XML string in publicPrivateKey looks like this (strings are shortened for readability):

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>t6tLd1Wi7PEkwPfx9KGP1Ps/5F2saXnOsCE2U....</Modulus>
   <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
   <P>3LJ5y4Vla7cS3XgmbIH5dQgppUHa+aSWavEOCbDRS/M....</P>
   <Q>1QyGIAnjv4YLcRVdwXtxWkijc+aZ496qIBZnCAUUD/E....</Q>
   <DP>0821dc0f+LBKOqIEvj4+2kJrNV5ueQesFBYkEsjPFM....</DP>
   <DQ>ugSzX2oDJwjdGKG1OOiVcmUWAm6IU4PpOxcUYtY8TC....</DQ>
   <InverseQ>LDQIQu+LSB6CSZBrGxNQthWi9mkuPGVZyDDr....</InverseQ>
   <D>qZm2bXKH8WwbsJ8ZlT3S1TbgUifppLrqSRkb8XqEcMv....</D> 
</RSAKeyValue>
```

The generated public key should be used in other apps (PHP / JavaScript / JAVA) to encrypt data. What part of the above XML defines the public key / what part do I have to send to the developers of the other apps?

And on the opposite side: What defines the private key / which part/parts do I have to store to be able to decrypt the data encrypted by my public key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSA keys for other parties are complicated to generate in .NET. If you send them this XML, not all your partners will be able to use it. General format for the public key is something like that:

[image]

The xml you've proived is a private key. To generate public key you should use the

```
string publicPrivateKey = RSA.ToXmlString(false);
```

Result will be like that:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>t6tLd1Wi7PEkwPfx9KGP1Ps/5F2saXnOsCE2U....</Modulus>
   <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

You may want to use other parties to get key in other format:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/RSACryptoPad.aspx

To port Java key to .NET format you can use this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/porting_java_public_key.aspx

Comment: I think you mean `.ToXmlString(false)`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring.aspx indicates the bool is includePrivateParameters.

Comment: ok, thanks. So I can send this XML ( RSA.ToXmlString(false); ) to the developers and they will be able to encrypt data with it in PHP, JAVA etc.?

Comment: @Mike Well, in ideal world it is so :) But you should ask them about public key format they need from you, and provide key in this format. Use links from answer, it is easy to regenerate the public key using them.

Comment: @VMAtn Thanks for your answer and the links. Do you think it would be better to store the public key in a X.509 certificate?

Comment: @Mike This is theme for the other question :) Generally, 'it depends' on: how you store the keys and how you interact with other parties. In my project we were glad with RSA.

Comment: @VMAtn ok, so with "format" you mean RSA, which means: there is only one RSA format? (sorry, but I'm a little bit confused now.. ;-)

Comment: @Mike Depending on system they may need only two numbers, or hash like from the picture I've provided, or something else. You should contact your partners and ask them yourself. And yes, I meant only RSA public key format, not other format like certificates or something. Sorry for my English, I'm trying to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

Exponent and modulus define the public key.

If you use [`RSA.ToXmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring.aspx) with its sole parameter `includePrivateParameters` set to `false`, you will only see the format

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>…</Modulus>
   <Exponent>…</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

output.

Comment: @Json: That means I have to send both strings, the modulus AND the Exponent to the developers? So a public key always consists of two separate strings, is that correct?